# Hive: How to calculate difference indat time?

Tags: mapreduce, hive, hiveql

I am using Hive 0.12,

Data:
customer_name val time
cust1 1 2014-05-19 05:12:43
cust1 2 2014-05-19 05:12:50 
cust1 3 2014-05-19 05:13:27
cust1 4 2014-05-19 05:14:14
cust2 1 2014-05-19 05:16:27
cust2 2 2014-05-19 05:17:01
cust2 3 2014-05-19 05:17:05

I want difference in time for each customer from val =1 to val=n.
Expected output:

cust1 00:01:31
cust2 00:00:39

Also date could change to next day for a customer. eg 
cust3 1 2014-05-19 23:59:00 
cust3 1 2014-05-20 00:02:25

expected output:
cust3 00:02:26

First question.Can this be done without UDF??
Second question. If no? How to do it using UDF??

Comment: Could you please format the input and the output properly, its very difficult to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer this I am making 2 assumptions (correct me if these are wrong as per your needs), first is that the timestamps are in the sorted order of value i.e. for cust1, the timestamp of value 1 is lesser than timestamp of value 2 and so on.

Second, the output is coming in terms of seconds. Please use any function on top of this to convert into your desired format.

Here is the data in correct format:

```
cust(string),val(string),ts(timestamp)
cust1,1,2014-05-19 05:12:43 
cust1,2,2014-05-19 05:12:50 
cust1,3,2014-05-19 05:13:27 
cust1,4,2014-05-19 05:14:14 
cust2,1,2014-05-19 05:16:27 
cust2,2,2014-05-19 05:17:01 
cust2,3,2014-05-19 05:17:05
```

Query:

> select cust,  unix_timestamp(max(ts)) - unix_timestamp(min(ts)) from
>   temp_txns GROUP BY cust

Output:

```
cust1   91
cust2   38
```

Hope this works for you.